Can you filter tasks between dates and labels?
Can you filter tasks between dates and labels? Something like this?
Filter on dates:
/projects/{project_id}/tasks?from=YYYY-MM-DD&to=YYYY-MM-DD
Filter on labels:
/projects/{project_id}/tasks?label=LABELNAME
We have looks over the API docs and tryed things liek the above but nothign seems to work for us. It makes a call to get just this weeks tasks with a label of xx very slow.
Have asked on git hub too - https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk/issues/36
